# How to download image from using url passed from adapter

Tags: android

I passed image url form adapter and want to download image from url :

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
buttonDownload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDownload);

String strImage= String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("URL"));

Glide.with(this)
    .load(strImage)
    .into(imageView);

buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //what to do
        }
    });
```

Comment: plz post your adapter code

Comment: Put your Glide code in onClick.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom callback within Glide for saving image after, like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
  .asBitmap()
  .load(url)
  .into(new Target<Bitmap>() {
     ...
});
```

You can set your target and get bitmap from it and then save it wherever you want it.

Check for more documentation on Glide official page:
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html

Comment: what to put in url in load()?

Comment: @MuPK you should use "strImage" as url from your sample of code.

Comment: can you please provide me with download code to internal storage?

Comment: You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762833/1537916 and try to google also for more, there are tons of examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void downloadFile(Context context,String file,String fileName)
{
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(context,file,fileName);
    downloadTask.execute(file);
}
```