# Download Image from URI And Store it in the Folder

Tags: android, uri, android-glide, android-download-manager, imageurl

I'm getting a list from the service side with 10 image Uris. I was showing all those images in the Fragment Pages using `Glide Library`, but glide is taking time to load the image and show it in the UI. so I was planning to download all the images and store locally so that during each page I can show directly from the path and show it in the UI.
Kindly suggest me the way to download and show it from the Path.

`Glide.with(getContext( )).load(ImageUri).into(ProductsImageView)` -  code used my be for Glide.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_image_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_text_layout"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/products_images"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/tomato"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761720/save-picture-to-storage-using-glide

Comment: @rahat- My intention is to download all the images first and save locally, before showing it in the UI. is that possible?

Comment: Cannot you tell Glide to cache images to disk?